# Codeigniter best approach to load data from model

Tags: codeigniter

Im trying to load data from a model if the data from a previously loaded model request is_numeric. I have written my code like this, though it doesn't work and i sort of get why. But i dont know how to get the content from the data['schedule_item'].

```
    $this->load->model('schedule_model');
    $this->load->model('partners_model');
    $data['schedule_item'] = $this->schedule_model->getAll();

    if(is_numeric($schedule_item['featured_partner1']) {

    $data['featured_partner1'] = $this->schedule_model->get_partner($schedule_item['featured_partner1']);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the wrong variable you have assigned the model values on the index of `$data` array not to `$schedule_item` so it is undefined `$schedule_item` will be accessible in view only when all the indexes of `$data` is converted to the variables  you should try to do this like

```
$this->load->model('schedule_model');
$this->load->model('partners_model');
$schedule_item=$this->schedule_model->getAll();
$data['schedule_item'] =$schedule_item;
if(is_numeric($schedule_item['featured_partner1']) {

$data['featured_partner1'] = $this->schedule_model->get_partner($schedule_item['featured_partner1']);

}
```

OR

```
$this->load->model('schedule_model');
$this->load->model('partners_model');
$data['schedule_item'] =$this->schedule_model->getAll();
if(is_numeric( $data['schedule_item']['featured_partner1']) {

$data['featured_partner1'] = $this->schedule_model->get_partner($schedule_item['featured_partner1']);

}
```